# Iterating over dynamically generated input field ids and using keyup to get their values in a separate input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, keyup

The mandatory div id gets different numbers of inputs field displayed in it dynamically. Each input field starting from the first gets an id attr1, then attr2,..attr[n]. I need a way to get this into an array that gets the value of each input field with keyup and puts them into a separate input field with id detail. 
   This code works but returns undefined in some case when the hard coded input field ids exceed the generated input field ids. Thanks.

```
   <div id="attributes"> <!--Start of Div Refreshed on Ajax Page Refresh-->
          <div id="mandatory">

          </div>
   </div>



     var total = '#attr1, #attr2';

     $("#attributes").on('keyup', total, function(){                    
                    update();
            })  

            function update() {
                $("#detail").val($('#attr1').val() + "," $('#attr2').val());
              }
```

Comment: is your issue the missing plus sign in this line? `$("#detail").val($('#attr1').val() + "," $('#attr2').val());`

Comment: No snapjs. The plus sign concatenates values of the input fields separated by a comma and puts them into the input field with id=detail. My issue is that i need a way to make this work by getting the generated dynamic input field ids stored and looped through grabbing their values o keyup and putting them in id=detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right your question I think you're looking for something like that:

```js
var fields = $("#mandatory").find("input"),
    ids = [];

fields.each(function(){
  $(this).on("keyup", function(){
     var val = "";
      ids = [];
      fields.each(function(){
        val += $(this).val() + (fields.length === ($(this).index() + 1) ? "": ", ");    
        
        ids.push($(this).get(0).id);
      });
      $("#detail").val(val);
      console.log(ids)
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="attributes">
<div id="mandatory">
<input id="one" class="one" value="54"/>
<input id="two" class="two" value="55"/>
<input id="three" class="three" value="587"/>
</div>
</div>
<input id="detail" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I think it'll take you down the right path.  In this example, any time a text input field is generated, an input event handler is attached to it that changes the value of a main textarea.  If this isn't quite what you're looking for, please let me know and I'll be happy to try to work it out more.

```js
document.getElementById('adder').onclick = function() {
  var dynamicTextbox = document.createElement('input');
  dynamicTextbox.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  dynamicTextbox.setAttribute('class', 'dynamicText');
  dynamicTextbox.addEventListener("input", function() {
    var allTextboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamicText');
    var allValues = '';
    for (var i=0; i < allTextboxes.length; i++) {
      allValues += allTextboxes[i].value;
    }
    document.getElementById('detail').value = allValues;

  });
  document.getElementById('textboxes').appendChild(dynamicTextbox);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="detail"></textarea>
<input id="adder" type="button" value="Add Text Field" />
<div id="textboxes"></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help me. This is similar but in my case i need the ids of the generated input fields to collected in an array because the number of input fields generated is changes; somestimes 2 or 13. So i need an array to easily grab all the input fields and grab their values on keyup into another field.

Comment: @Maxenem How about now?  I don't think you need to give them all different ids, but if they all have the same class that should be sufficient.